# check a checkbox and refresh the page, how to restore their state

Tags: refresh

My problem is that when I try to check a checkbox and refresh the page, the checkbox returns to being uncheck. I am using Sharepoint 2010.
i want them to retain values

Comment: afaik you can't retain values after a refresh, even the ViewState only works for postback. so you'll have to save the value somewhere and set it on the page on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible, but the only idea comes to mind is to save values in the ViewState property as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx)